# UIDocumentInteractionController PopOver on iPad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

When you display a UIActionSheet on the iPad, it appears as a centered UIPopover with no arrow.

I have a UIDocumentInteractionController, and when I call presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:, I am looking for the same behavior with the popover that appears there.  Anyway to do that?  I know you can have no arrow on a popover by setting the PermittedArrowDirections to 0, but that doesn't seem to be an option here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIActivityController instead

```
let url = #Your File URL#
var activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX, y: view.frame.midY,
                                                                          width: 0, height: 0)
```